# DAL for Windows Service

Tags: c#, winforms, data-access-layer

I am in a process of writing a windows service which will read an XML file generated periodically and update a DB. I have generally seen a 3 tier architecture in web apps (Presentation, BL & DAL as class library). I have the following questions

1. Should we follow the same approach for the desktop app/windows service?
2. Do we need to create instance members for DAL class or should it be static?
3. Is there any tool that can quickly generate the DAL layer for the mapped DB?

   Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx (I'm not a fan of NHibernate as I find it bloatware)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to use LINQ, NHibertate or Entity.
A lot of projects running on .NET 4.0 still use old fashioned  ADO.NET.

LINQ to SQL is not something to be proud of in your application.
As for Entity Framework or NHibernate, those are ORM APIs and have their highly beneficial usage scenarios, but also have a steep learning curve, and are less efficient in performance than using inline queries or Stored Procedure (But offer a lot better extensibility and maintainability). Another benefit in using those ORM libraries is that you don't have to write SQL in most cases, but it can give you some headaches if you have complex scenarios.
**And you can use Entity Framework with .NET 3.5**

If you are comfortable with SQL and the project has not a big team allocated, there's nothing wrong at all with using inline queries or stored procedures. 
Or, if you like, you can use something like MyBatis, which puplates objects using reflection based on a provided XML file. (I think they have generation tools).

So my opinion, if you have a big database, but don't expect complex queries, the cost of learning Entity Framework is justified.
But if you have a small database but with complex queries, which are already written somewhere, it would be a huge mistake to use Entity or NHibernate...

Answer (score 1):

n-tier architecture and other solution architecture give us some ideas and depend on some project condition and just one of these condition is the kind of our projects.

if you use 3-tire in a web app it does not mean it is not used in other type of projects.

so as an answer for first question i say that n-tier is a good(not best) solution for any project that has transactions on a database.use 3-tier (even 4-tier) and do not worry.it is common strategy for developing windows services

for your second question : yes you do , create them.using static method is not a way to generating a application based-on n-tier architecture.

for your third question: yes there is.

if you use .net framework 2 ,generate the DAL layer with NHibernate.
if you use .net framework 3 and 3.5 ,generate the DAL layer with LinQ.
and if you use .net framework 4 ,generate the DAL layer with ADO.net entity Framework modeler.

Comment: Does LinQ generate stored procedure and c# code for DAL? I found this http://code.google.com/p/crudgeneratoraspnetwinform/wiki/CRUDGenerator, is that a useful tool? Since i am beginner in C# i just dono what framework to use.

Comment: Yes.it does but in its way.No just use LinQ or Entity Framework.these tool are prefect.if you did not use them yet you can not understand the power of them.
Use dot.net framework 4 with Visual Studio 2010.